# T/F: If a subspace S has a basis B with 2 elements then S is a plane.

Tags: linear-algebra

I believe the answer is yes, because even if the basis is in $R$2, then the basis would represent the xy-plane. For $R$3 and beyond, two elements of a basis should always form a plane Is my interpretation correct?

Comment: Is the vector space generated by the functions $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ a plane? Not every vector space is ${\bf R}^n$.

Comment: I mean this definitely depends on what you mean by a plane. But if you define a plane to be a two dimensional vector space, then yes, this is correct.

Comment: For $2\le n<\infty$  a $2$-dimenional vector-subspace of $ \Bbb R^n$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb R^2.$